# Apply functions and arguments by row wise evaluation

Tags: r

I'm working on a half-automated report that consists of dozens of various plots. I've created an excel/csv table to manage the contents of the report that lists rowwise the various data items to be plotted, with arguments such as titles etc in columns. I have created custom functions for each plot type and they work fine.

Where I got to a standstill is the sort of top function that would go through the dataframe row wise, take function id, apply the corresponding function and take the values from other columns of the row as arguments.

A simplified example is the following

```
dat <- data.frame(data_item=seq(1:5), function_id=c(1,2,3,2,3), 
                  x=sample(1:5,5), y=sample(1:5,5))
```

Resulting in a dataframe:

```
data_item function_id x y
1         1           1 5 2
2         2           2 4 4
3         3           3 1 3
4         4           2 2 5
5         5           3 3 1
```

Then I have functions for plots, say:

```
fun1 <- function(df, data_item, x,y){ggplot(df %>% dplyr::filter(data_item == !!data_item),aes(x,y))+geom_point(col = "red")}
fun2 <- function(df, data_item, x,y){ggplot(df %>% dplyr::filter(data_item == !!data_item),aes(x,y))+geom_point(col = "blue")}
fun3 <- function(df, data_item, x,y){ggplot(df %>% dplyr::filter(data_item == !!data_item),aes(x,y))+geom_point(col = "green")}
```

I need to evaluate the `dat` dataframe row wise and apply `fun1`if `function_id`equals 1, `fun2`if it equals 2 and so on, with `data_item, x, y`as arguments for that function.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
I adapted Michael Scott's solution almost copy/paste and ended up with:

```
apply(test1,1,function(row){
  item <- row[1]
  rank_order <- row[2]
  graph_type <- row[3]
  plot_title <- row[4]
  sub_title <- row[5]
  x_axis_title <- row[6]
  y_axis_title <- row[7]
  caption <- row[8]
  data_set <- row[9]
  weight_basis <- row[10]
  funcs[[graph_type]](test1,item,rank_order,plot_title,sub_title,x_axis_title,y_axis_title,caption,data_set,weight_basis)
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
funcs <- list(fun1,fun2,fun3)
apply(dat,1,function(row){
  data_item <- row[1]
  function_id <- row[2]
  x <- row[3]
  y <- row[4]
  funcs[[function_id]](dat,data_item,x,y)
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Do I understand correctly that `funcs[[function_id]]` refers to the position of function in the `funcs` list?

Comment: I've been trying to implement your solution to my real case and now I understood that my example was a bit too simplified. Namely, the aesthetics data I'm using (`x`and `y` in the example) are in a _another_ data frame. How would your solution look like if `x`and `y` were in, say, `dat1`? 
Thanks in advance, this piece of code is a bit over my head at this moment.

Comment: Could you combined your dataframes?

Comment: No, but after giving it another thought, it should actually not matter after all - the actual plot functions call the dataset themselves.

I got back to the beginning, took your example and essentially made a copy/paste piece of code with only changing the data and variable names. Got an error: `Error in funcs[[graph_type]](test1, item, rank_order, plot_title, sub_title,  :  attempt to apply non-function`.
Confused.

Comment: Hmm, could one possible reason for your solution not working on my real data be that there are several character vectors in the data frame that are used as arguments (like `plot_title`)? My example had only numerical variables and `apply` does not play with character vectors? What can I do about that?

Comment: apply should work fine with character values. It sounds like you are now trying to use something as a function that is not actually a function. If you want to share your new code I can look into it more.

Comment: Try changing 
graph_type <- row[3]
to
graph_type <- as.numeric(row[3])
If that does not work I will need more information